# Evaluate at which size data.table is faster than data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

Can someone please help me evaluate at which size of a data frame using data.table is faster for searches? In my use case the data frames will be 24,000 rows and 560,000 rows. Blocks of 40 rows are always singled out for further use.

Example:
DF is a data frame with 120 rows, 7 columns (x1 to x7); "string" occupies the first 40 rows of x1.

DF2 is 1000 times DF => 120,000 rows

For the size of DF data.table is slower, for the size of DF2 it is faster.

Code:

```
> DT <- data.table(DF)
> setkey(DT, x1)
> 
> DT2 <- data.table(DF2)
> setkey(DT2, x1)
> 
> microbenchmark(DF[DF$x1=="string", ], unit="us")
Unit: microseconds
                    expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
 DF[DF$x1 == "string", ] 282.578 290.8895 297.0005 304.5785 2394.09   100
> microbenchmark(DT[.("string")], unit="us")
Unit: microseconds
            expr      min       lq  median      uq      max neval
 DT[.("string")] 1473.512 1500.889 1536.09 1709.89 6727.113   100
> 
> 
> microbenchmark(DF2[DF2$x1=="string", ], unit="us")
Unit: microseconds
                      expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 DF2[DF2$x1 == "string", ] 31090.4 34694.74 35537.58 36567.18 61230.41   100
> microbenchmark(DT2[.("string")], unit="us")
Unit: microseconds
             expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 DT2[.("string")] 1327.334 1350.801 1391.134 1457.378 8440.668   100
```

Comment: +1. Maybe just use a data.table but apply a different subsetting function to it, selected from the list `methods(\`[\`)`? Also, if you want a substantial answer, you might want to create example data for DF and DF2

Comment: @Frank: I tried subset(DT2[.("string")]) and it was a bit slower. Is this what was on your mind? DF data: x1: string, always the same for 40 rows, x2: string, x3 to x7: date. DF2 is just DF copied in 1,000 times. I need to select the 40 rows with the same string.

Comment: I'm thinking that if your data is so small that data.frame subsetting is appropriate, you can always do `\`[.data.frame\`(DT,DT$x1=="string")` or something similar, and keep your data in a data.table either way. Also, if `x1=="string"` for the first 40 rows, you should just select the first 40 rows, right?

Comment: If "string" is in the first 40 rows, I guess data.frame (that performs line search) will have peformances similar to data.table... you should do something more random...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
timings <- sapply(1:10, function(n) {
  DF <- data.frame(id=rep(as.character(seq_len(2^n)), each=40), val=rnorm(40*2^n), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  DT <- data.table(DF, key="id")     
  tofind <- unique(DF$id)[n-1]
  print(microbenchmark( DF[DF$id==tofind,],
                        DT[DT$id==tofind,],
                        DT[id==tofind],
                        `[.data.frame`(DT,DT$id==tofind,),
                        DT[tofind]), unit="ns")$median
})

matplot(1:10, log10(t(timings)), type="l", xlab="log2(n)", ylab="log10(median (ns))", lty=1)
legend("topleft", legend=c("DF[DF$id == tofind, ]",
                           "DT[DT$id == tofind, ]",
                           "DT[id == tofind]",
                           "`[.data.frame`(DT,DT$id==tofind,)",
                           "DT[tofind]"),
       col=1:5, lty=1)
```

[image]

## Jan. 2016: Update to `data.table_1.9.7`

`data.table` has made a few updates since this was written (a bit more overhead added to `[.data.table` as a few more arguments / robustness checks have been built in, but also the introduction of auto-indexing). Here's an updated version as of the January 13, 2016 version of 1.9.7 from GitHub:

[image: jan_2016]

The main innovation is that the third option now leverages auto-indexing. The main conclusion remains the same -- if your table is of any nontrivial size (roughly larger than 500 observations), `data.table`'s within-frame calling is faster.

*(notes about the updated plot: some minor things (un-logging the y-axis, expressing in microseconds, changing the x-axis labels, adding a title), but one non-trivial thing is I updated the `microbenchmark`s to add some stability in the estimates--namely, I set the `times` argument to `as.integer(1e5/2^n)`)*

Comment: Does `\`[.data.frame\`(DT,DT$id==tofind)` keep up with the DF one?

Comment: @Frank Yes, it does (as expected).

Comment: I think using normal `data.table` syntax will be a tiny bit faster: `DT[id == tofind]` since you won't have to call `$`

Comment: @Roland: thanks for the really opening demonstration! So, it is really up to the task in combination with number of rows to decide for DT. So in general one can say for small size DFs it is better to stick with DF or use Franks (thanks for that) example using data.frame on DT. correct me if i am wrong. Great answer and comments!

Comment: @chriscross Yeah, I think that's the takeaway, though I think data.tables are preferable for other reasons, too (nicer syntax, other operations that are fast, ...), so I'd say you're safe just abandoning vanilla data.frames. (By the way, data.tables are just a special type of data.frame; that's why `\`[.data.frame\`` works on them.)

Comment: @eddi That doesn't seem to matter much.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, the green line uses auto-index optimization now (with default options). Feel free to add an update with the current version to my answer.

Comment: @MichaelChirico and Roland: Interesting. +1. Tweeted here: https://twitter.com/MattDowle/status/687397266513072129