# Is there a way to speed up subsetting of smaller data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, subset

I have to subset a sequence of `data.frame`s frequently (millions of times each run). The `data.frame`s are of approximate size 200 rows x 30 columns. Depending on the state, the values in the `data.frame` change from one iteration to the next. Thus, doing one subset in the beginning is not working.

In contrast to the question, [when a data.table starts to be faster than a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20176421/5784831), I am looking for a speed-up of subsetting for a given size of the `data.frame`/`data.table`

The following minimum reproducible example shows, that `data.frame` seems to be the fastest:

```
library(data.table)
nmax <- 1e2 # for 1e7 the results look as expected: data.table is really fast!
set.seed(1)
x<-runif(nmax,min=0,max=10)
y<-runif(nmax,min=0,max=10)
DF<-data.frame(x,y)
DT<-data.table(x,y)

summary(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  setkey(DT,x,y),
  times = 10L, unit = "us"))

#               expr    min     lq    mean  median      uq     max neval
# 1 setkey(DT, x, y) 70.326 72.606 105.032 80.3985 126.586 212.877    10

summary(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  DF[DF$x>5, ], 
  `[.data.frame`(DT,DT$x < 5,),
  DT[x>5],
  times = 100L, unit = "us"))
#                             expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
# 1                 DF[DF$x > 5, ]  41.815  45.426  52.40197  49.9885  57.4010  82.110   100
# 2 `[.data.frame`(DT, DT$x < 5, )  43.716  47.707  58.06979  53.5995  61.2020 147.873   100
# 3                      DT[x > 5] 205.273 214.777 233.09221 222.0000 231.6935 900.164   100
```

Is there anything I can do to improve performance?

**Edit after input**:

- I am running a discrete event simulation and for each event I have to search in a list (I don't mind whether it is a `data.frame` or `data.table`). Most likely, I could implement a different approach, but then I have to re-write the code which was developed over more than 3 years. At the moment, this is not an option. But if there is no way to get it faster this might become an option in the future.
- Technically, it is not a sequence of `data.frames` but just one `data.frame`, which changes with each iteration. However, this has no impact on "how to get the subset faster" and I hope that the question is now more comprehensive.

Comment: Unless you are subsetting virtually random selection of the data maybe you want to create a list of existing subsets that you can refer to instead of refitering the dataframe in the same ways over and over?

Comment: There is overhead involved in data.table subsetting. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20179189/1412059

Comment: You should ask a proper question about your actual problem. If you are subsetting data.frames millions of times your approach is wrong.

Comment: Please reopen the question. I can't find an answer anywhere and I think the question should be clear after the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see a performance boost by **converting to matrices**. This is a viable alternative if the whole content of your `data.frame` is numerical (or can be converted without too much trouble).

Here we go. First I modified the data to have it with size 200x30:

```
library(data.table)
nmax = 200
cmax = 30
set.seed(1)
x<-runif(nmax,min=0,max=10)
DF = data.frame(x)
for (i in 2:cmax) {
  DF = cbind(DF, runif(nmax,min=0,max=10))
  colnames(DF)[ncol(DF)] = paste0('x',i)
}
DT = data.table(DF)
DM = as.matrix(DF)    # # # or data.matrix(DF) if you have factors
```

And the comparison, ranked from quickest to slowest:

```
summary(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  DM[DM[, 'x']>5, ], # # # # Quickest
  as.matrix(DF)[DF$x>5, ], # # # # Still quicker with conversion
  DF[DF$x>5, ], 
  `[.data.frame`(DT,DT$x < 5,),
  DT[x>5],
  times = 100L, unit = "us"))

#                             expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
# 1            DM[DM[, "x"] > 5, ]  13.883  19.8700  22.65164  22.4600  24.9100   41.107   100
# 2      as.matrix(DF)[DF$x > 5, ] 141.100 181.9140 196.02329 195.7040 210.2795  304.989   100
# 3                 DF[DF$x > 5, ] 198.846 238.8085 260.07793 255.6265 278.4080  377.982   100
# 4 `[.data.frame`(DT, DT$x < 5, ) 212.342 268.2945 346.87836 289.5885 304.2525 5894.712   100
# 5                      DT[x > 5] 322.695 396.3675 465.19192 428.6370 457.9100 4186.487   100
```

If your use-case involves querying multiple times the data, then you can do the conversion only once and increase the speed by one order of magnitude.

Comment: Cool, I already gave up, but it seems there is always somebody with a good idea :-)